# Some property of GL(2,R) and GL(2,Z)

Tags: modular-forms, general-linear-group

I am trying to show that there exists a family of matrices $(M_n)$ in $GL(2, \mathbb{R}) $ such that $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}) M_n GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is the same for every n and $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}) M_n $ is different for every n.

I tried to simplify it by setting
$$M_n = \begin{bmatrix}a_n & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

and find some suitable $a_n$, but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: How about taking a generic matrix $M\in GL(2,R)$  and the family of matrices $M_n$ of the form $g_nM$, where $g_n$ are randomly chosen in $GL(2,Z)$?